# Is there a way to include the ~ in the output of realpath

Tags: shell, sed, realpath

`realpath` is very nice in that it gives you a simple way to get the real path of a file, but I can't figure out a way to satisfy my needs (without doing my own string manipulation, and therefore potentially missing the corner cases that a dedicated utility presumably has found and solved).  In a nutshell, I want to include `~` in the path that it returns, so it can be valid across machines.

So if I'm in `~/bin` and I type `realpath --some-option script.sh` I want it to return `~/bin/script.sh` instead of `bin/script.sh`, which is what I get if the option I use is `--relative-base=$HOME`, and instead of `/Users/brandon/bin/script.sh`, which is what I get if I use no options.

Is there some way to get what I want from `realpath`, or is there some other utility that does what I want in a simple way?  Or is the only real option to just pipe through `sed` to get what I want?

(P.S. I'm on OS X, but I've got GNU utilities installed, in case those are needed... I'm not sure if that's where `realpath` came from or if it's now installed by default on more recent versions of OS X.)

Comment: In general, having the `~` is harmful for purposes other than human display -- shells only do tilde expansion in a small set of cases, and `open()` and the like won't honor it at all.

Comment: It's obviously not difficult to just pipe through sed, but it seems like there *ought* to be something already builtin that I'm overlooking... otherwise its   `realpath ../some/path/ | sed -e "s|$HOME|~|"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I'll be writing the code that consumes the paths, so I can make sure it handles `~` okay.  But your point might be the reason that no one else has seen fit to add this option to `realpath`.

Comment: Assuming you're capturing to a shell variable, one can of course do something like `[[ $path = "$HOME"/* ]] && path="~/"${path#"$HOME/"}` with less overhead than starting an external command such as `sed` (and fewer bugs -- no chance of characters in the home directory name being treated as regex content rather than literals).

Answer (score 2):

Even the current version of OSX (10.11.3) does *not* come with a `realpath` utility, so yours must indeed come from the GNU `coreutils` Homebrew package.

In fact, you can easily verify that with `realpath` itself; e.g.:

```
$ realpath "$(which realpath)"
/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.24/bin/grealpath
```

Using `--relative-base="$HOME"` and simply prepending `~/`, as in [Bujiraso's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674266/45375) is the simplest solution in your case.

Let me propose an alternative that:

- Makes do without `realpath`, because its presence cannot be assumed on OSX machines.

  - A Perl one-liner is used instead (Python would also be an option).
- Uses `$HOME` instead of `~`, as basing a path on `$HOME` is the *safer* choice (assuming a *shell* expands the path):

  - `$HOME` is safer, because it allows the *entire* path string to be double-quoted when it is passed to the shell, without having to worry about individually quoting (escaping) embedded spaces and other shell metacharacters; by contrast, with a `~`-prefixed path you'd either have to quote *individual* characters in the path or selectively leave the `~/` prefix *unquoted* (`~/"path/..."`).

```
absPath=$(perl -MCwd -le 'print Cwd::abs_path(shift)' "script.sh")
abstractPath="\$HOME${absPath#"$HOME"}"
```

The result would be something like *literal* `$HOME/bin/script.sh`, which, when interpreted by the shell, would expand to a then-current-user-specific path.

If you define an `abstractHomePath()` `bash` function as printed below, you can use:

```
abstractPath=$(abstractHomePath "script.sh")  # -> '$HOME/bin/script.sh'
```

---

**`abstractHomePath` Bash function:**

```
# Given a relative or absolute path, returns an absolute path in which the path
# prefix that is the current user's home directory is replaced with literal
# '$HOME' so as to yield an abstract path that can later be expanded in a 
# different user's context to get the analogous path. 
#
# If the input path resolves to an absolute path that is *not* prefixed with
# the current user's home diretory path, the absolute path is returned as -is.
#
# Note that any symlinks in the path are resolved to their ultimate targets
# first and that the path is normalized.
#
# Examples:
#    abstractHomePath ~ # -> '$HOME'
#    abstractHomePath /Users/jdoe/Downloads # -> '$HOME/Downloads'
#    abstractHomePath /tmp # -> '/private/tmp' -  symlink resolved, but no $HOME prefix
# Prerequisites:
#    Requires Perl v5+
abstractHomePath() {
  local absPath=$(perl -MCwd -le 'print Cwd::abs_path(shift)' "$1")
  if [[ $absPath == "$HOME"* ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "\$HOME${absPath#"$HOME"}"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$absPath"
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`realpath` itself does not seem to have this functionality, however a simple solution might be to echo the prefix of tilde+slash itself, followed by the relative realpath. That is, you could use a combination of the relative-base and echo, instead of sed.
For example:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ echo "~/$(realpath --relative-base=$HOME bin/myScript)"
~/bin/myScript
```